# Writing an instant webhook?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get clients of an app to request data using jQuery's `$.getJSON`, the URL they are fetching from will essentially be a tracking code that returns `OK` i.e. `http://foo.bar/tracking?uid=001&action=button1+pressed`

The idea is that we get information of how users are using the app in real time. How do I leverage this tracking and get it to instantly show up on another page, along with data from every client, without delay? I've seen services like Pusher, but these tend to have rate limited services. Any way to do this on Apache at scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking fo websockets [PHP](http://socketo.me/), [NodeJS](http://socket.io/), [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)